# Sending vendor content type with jMeter throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, http, jmeter, mime-types, content-type

I need to add a custom content-type to a file uploaded with a multipart request. To do this, I put vendor content-type `application/vnd.anything.process+json;ver=1` as a `MIME type` for this file.
Unfortunately, jMeter throws `IllegalArgumentException`, because it recognizes `;` as an invalid character in the content-type specification.

If this is not supported, then how to send a file with a content-type that contains `;`? I tried to use a postman and record outgoing HTTP call from jMeter, but it fails with the same exception.

[image]

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MIME type may not contain reserved characters
    at org.apache.http.util.Args.check(Args.java:36)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(ContentType.java:229)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(ContentType.java:241)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.setupHttpEntityEnclosingRequestData(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1575)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.handleMethod(HTTPHC4Impl.java:886)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:641)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:635)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confirmation, it is a bug in JMeter https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65024

Answer (score 0):

If you're **absolutely sure** that the content type should look exactly like you described you can work it around by switching the "Client implementation" to `Java`

The setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

If you want to change the client implementation for all the HTTP Request samplers in a single shot you can do it using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element

Comment: Thanks, it fixes the issue partially, but I'm not sure if it is the best idea. It looks like Java implementation does not support local paths. Also the form expects MIME type for the file. It should be possible to send even simpler onces, like `text/html; charset=UTF-8`